# How can I show the value of a function on Manipulate alongside the plot?

Tags: manipulate, dynamic

Suppose I have the following `Manipulate` function,

```
Manipulate[Plot[Sin[a x + b], {x, 0, 6}], {a, 1, 4}, {b, 0, 10}]
```

running this plots the function for given `a` and `b`. As follow for example:

[image]

for each given `a` and `b` I want to show the value of `a*b` on the same module, so for the example above it would show `a*b=10` I wonder how one does that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

```
Manipulate[
 Grid[{
   {Row[{"a * b = ", a*b}]},
   {Plot[Sin[a x + b], {x, 0, 6}, ImageSize -> 400]}
   }, Spacings -> {1, 1}, Frame -> All],
 {{a, 1, "a"}, 1, 4, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{b, 0, "b"}, 0, 10, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 TrackedSymbols :> {a, b}]
```